# Unable to install sbt-eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, fedora-21

I"m trying to install sbt-eclipse on but I keep getting the following error below when running `sbt` or `sbt update`.

error

> [info] Loading global plugins from /home/atbyrd/.sbt/0.13/plugins
>   [info] Updating
>   {file:/home/atbyrd/.sbt/0.13/plugins/}global-plugins... [info]
>   Resolving org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.1 ... [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: configuration not found in
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: 'compile'. It was required from
>   default#global-plugins;0.0 provided [warn]
>     :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: sbt.ResolveException:
>   unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3:
>   configuration not found in org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3:
>   'compile'. It was required from default#global-plugins;0.0 provided
>     at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)    at
>   sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)  at
>   sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)  at
>   sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)  at
>   sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)  at
>   sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)    at
>   sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)     at
>   sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
>     at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
>     at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
>     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:102)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)    at
>   sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)    at
>   sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)     at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
>     at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)  at
>   sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)  at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1161)
>     at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1159)
>     at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1182)
>     at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1180)
>     at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)    at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1184)     at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1179)     at
>   sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)   at
>   sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1187)     at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1152)   at
>   sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1130)   at
>   scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)  at
>   sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)    at
>   sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>     at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
>     at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)   at
>   sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)   at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)    at
>   sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)    at
>   sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
>     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [error] (*:update)
>   sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency:
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: configuration not found in
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.3: 'compile'. It was required from
>   default#global-plugins;0.0 provided

~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

resolvers += "mvnrepository" at "http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/"

resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases")

resolvers += Resolver.sbtPluginRepo("releases")
```

cat ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "3.0.0")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was related to compatibility problems. SBT isn't directly compatible with JDK 8. I was able to resolve this by adding the dependency below.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.2.0"
```

Comment: this was close, but there are extra backticks I had to remove around the "0.2.0". I put this in the ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt file, and it all worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried the "best answer" and it didn't solve my problem. I learned that I was simply using the wrong `sbt` version. When I installed `sbt 0.13.11` instead, the plugin error was solved.